# Recursive JSON to get an expression

Tags: python-3.x

I got a JSON  with which I need to calculate variables recursively. If you see the example JSON to calculate A_name I need to first calculate A1_name using i1+i2 which is given to a1_name. The calculation expression is given in expression. I'm not able to understand how to traverse and get proper calculations.

The final goal is to add columns to the data or rename existing columns. If we see from the JSON.

case:1
 to derive the column v1 from the data pick the column F

case:2
 to derive T1 we have to add E1+Co1+D1(expression at each level), but each E1 might be derived from a different calculation or column.

Basically when we see the internal when columns=[] it means it is the existing column already in the data. When I am executing a script I need to get these calculations step by step by decoding the JSON.

```
[
{
  "name": "V1",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "F",
      "columns": [],
      "index": 0,
      "expression": null
    }
  ],
  "index": 0,
  "expression": null
},
{
  "name": "V2",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "M2",
      "columns": [],
      "index": 0,
      "expression": null
    }
  ],
  "index": 1,
  "expression": null
},
{
  "name": "T1",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "E1",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "C1",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "C11",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 0,
              "expression": null
            }
          ],
          "index": 0,
          "expression": null
        },
        {
          "name": "C2",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "C21",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 0,
              "expression": null
            }
          ],
          "index": 1,
          "expression": null
        },
        {
          "name": "R1",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "N1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 0,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "Cn1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 1,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "M1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 2,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "L1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 3,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "S1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 4,
              "expression": null
            }
          ],
          "index": 2,
          "expression": "0+1+2+3+4"
        }
      ],
      "index": 0,
      "expression": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Co1",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "Co",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "cou1",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 0,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "Cou2",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 1,
              "expression": null
            }
          ],
          "index": 0,
          "expression": "0+1"
        }
      ],
      "index": 1,
      "expression": null
    },
    {
      "name": "D1",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "P1",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "P12",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 0,
              "expression": null
            },
            {
              "name": "Con",
              "columns": [],
              "index": 1,
              "expression": null
            }
          ],
          "index": 0,
          "expression": "0+1"
        }
      ],
      "index": 2,
      "expression": null
    }
  ],
  "index": 2,
  "expression": "0+1+2"
}
```

]

Code I tried:

```
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
if isinstance(json_input, dict):
    for key, value in json_input.items():
        if key == lookup_key:
            yield value
        else:
            yield from item_generator(value, lookup_key)
elif isinstance(json_input, list):
    for item in json_input:
        yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)

 def get_json_keys(json_to_decode):
   column_name = json_to_decode['columns'][0]['name']
   return column_name

  for each in each_to_cal:    
     derived_name = each['name']
     if (each['expression']==None):
        column_name = get_json_keys(each)
        print('derived col:%s and org_col:%s'%(derived_name,column_name))
     else:
        indxs = re.findall(r'\d+', each['expression'])
        for col,indx in zip(each['columns'],indxs):
           derived_name = col['name']
           if (col['expression']==None):
              column_name = get_json_keys(each)
              print('derived col:%s and org_col:%s'%(derived_name,column_name))
           else:
              indxs = re.findall(r'\d+', each['expression'])
      print(indxs)
```

Can anyone post an effective way to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit better? How exactly should the variables' names be computed? You mention the calculation expression but then most of them are null. Provide a full example on how to calculate a name based on the expression.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with the code you tried? Did you get an exception? If so, include the full traceback in the body of the question. If you just got incorrect results, show what you got and what you expected instead.

Comment: @GRoutar edited with more explanation and changed Json to make it understandable

Comment: @Anji please also format your code, that indentation is horrible

Comment: If `"expression": null`, should the program not include it in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something like what you're looking for:

```
import json

def parse_var(var_, n=0):
    variables = {}
    def _parse_var(var, n=0, shallow=False):
        var_dict = {}
        for col in var["columns"]:
            var_dict[str(col["index"])] = col["name"] if shallow else _parse_var(col, n + 1)
        if not var_dict:
            return var["name"]
        if not var["expression"]:
            e = "{" + "} + {".join(var_dict.keys()) + "}"
        else:
            e = var["expression"]
            for i in var_dict.keys():
                e = e.replace(i, "{"+i+"}")
            e = e.replace("}{", "")
        for a, b in var_dict.items():
                e = e.replace("{"+a+"}", b)  
        if not shallow:
            expl = _parse_var(var, shallow=True)
        else:
            expl = ""
            # print('\t'*n + var["name"], "=", parse_var(var, shallow=True), "=", e)
        variables[var["name"]] = e, expl
        return e
    _parse_var(var_)
    return variables

def parse(json_dict):
    for expr in json_dict:
        variables = parse_var(expr)
        for var, (equ, expl) in variables.items():
            print(f"{var} = {expl} = {equ}")
        # print(expr["name"], "=", parse_var(expr))

>>> parse(json.loads(s))
V1 = F = F
V2 = M2 = M2
C1 = C11 = C11
C2 = C21 = C21
R1 = N1+Cn1+M1+L1+S1 = N1+Cn1+M1+L1+S1
E1 = C1 + C2 + R1 = C11 + C21 + N1+Cn1+M1+L1+S1
Co = cou1+Cou2 = cou1+Cou2
Co1 = Co = cou1+Cou2
P1 = P12+Con = P12+Con
D1 = P1 = P12+Con
T1 = E1+Co1+D1 = C11 + C21 + N1+Cn1+M1+L1+S1+cou1+Cou2+P12+Con
```

This will recursively calculate the expression for each variable.

EDIT: Provide solution that prints each equation it finds.

EDIT 2: Interprets the value of `var["expression"]`, uses default sum of variables if not found.

Note: If you set `T1` to be (E1+Co1)/D1 in the expression variable, you will get unexpected output because `D1` is not in parentheses. To fix this, put parentheses *everywhere you might think they will be needed* or use the following line instead of line 14:

```
e = e.replace(i, "({"+i+"})")
```

EDIT 3: Changed to return a `variables` dictionary, each of which contains the "equation" (full recursive equation) and the "explanation" (shallow equation).

EDIT 4: fixed for >10-variable equations.

Comment: solution is somewhat helpfull but to get T1 I need results 
-->R1 = N1+cn1+M1+L1+S1
-->C1 = C11
-->C2 = C21
E1 = C1+C2+R1

similarly 
-->Co = Cou1+Cou2
-->Co1 = Co

Comment: @Anji Edited the answer to print out each equation that it finds, as well as the expansion.

Comment: this is good.. but the ultimate goal here to use expression.. since it has '+' in expression it is ok but if the expression is changed something like n1+(cn1/m1)+(L1/s1) then I believe we cant achieve the final result...

Comment: @Anji You're right, I added support for that. (I changed `T1` in your last example to have division.)

Comment: excellent.. its printing as expected need to test few scenarios if it can return var['name'] and expression that needs to be calculated that gives us a correct function to pass any dataset...

Comment: ,I am trying to return var['name'] and calculated string to the function parse not able to get... that is returning v1,v2,c1 to the parse function so that I can calculate one by one... That would be really helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201537/discussion-between-rassar-and-anji).

Comment: @Anji I updated the answer to work for 10+ variables

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay have been out until now